# How to sync revisions when calling bulkDocs on pouchdb instance in RxDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, pouchdb, bulkupdate, rxdb

I'm trying to bulk update some RxDB docs, since RxDB does not have a bulk update function I have to use the bulkDocs function on the built in pouchdb instance. I can successfully do this but then my revisions are out of sync. Is there a way to sync rxdb revisions with pouchdb when using the pouchdb instance?

My code:

```
async bulkUpdate(docs) {
  let db = await ProjectDB.get();
  let data = [];
  let nodeDocs = await db.collections.nodes.find().exec();

  _.each(docs, doc => {
    let matchingDoc = _.find(nodeDocs, n => {return n.id === doc._id});
    if (matchingDoc) {
      data.push(_.omit(_.assign({_id: matchingDoc.id, _rev: matchingDoc.revision}, matchingDoc.toJSON(), doc), "id"));
    }
  });

  await db.collections.nodes.pouch.bulkDocs({docs: data}, {force: true}).then(docs => {
    _.each(docs, doc => {
      console.log(doc);
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: need to emit a change event for the relevant rxdb documents to sync with.

I sourced some code from the rxdb repo and tweaked:

```
static async bulkUpdate(collection, docs) {
    let db = await ProjectDB.get();
    let docIds = _.map(docs, doc => {return doc.id});
    let rxDocs = await collection.findByIds(docIds);
    let updatedDocs = new Map();
    let bulkUpdateDocs = [];

    _.each(docs, doc => {
      let matchingDoc = rxDocs.get(doc.id);
      if (matchingDoc) {
        bulkUpdateDocs.push(_.omit(_.assign({_id: matchingDoc.id, _rev: matchingDoc.revision}, matchingDoc.toJSON(), doc), "id"));
        updatedDocs.set(doc.id, _.assign({_rev: matchingDoc.revision}, matchingDoc.toJSON(), doc))
      }
    });

    let startTime, okResults;
    const results = await db.lockedRun(async () => {
      startTime = Date.now();
      return await collection.pouch.bulkDocs({docs: bulkUpdateDocs});
    });
    const endTime = Date.now();

    okResults = results.filter((r: any) => r.ok);

    // for each updated doc a change event is emitted that the rxdb collection may subscribe to...
    _.each(okResults, r => {
      let originalDoc = rxDocs.get(r.id);
      let updatedDoc = updatedDocs.get(r.id);
      if (originalDoc) {
        updatedDoc._rev = r.rev;

        let changeEvent = new RxChangeEvent(
          'UPDATE',
          updatedDoc.id,
          updatedDoc,
          db.token,
          collection.name,
          false,
          startTime,
          endTime,
          originalDoc._data,
          originalDoc,
        );
        originalDoc.$emit(changeEvent);
      }
    });
  }
```